# How to access posted server json data from client

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I am writing my first app using net 2.1 and angular 6.  I am able to post the json data from net 2.1 on an iis express webpage from visual studio using C#.

I am able to post data from the front end, angular/typscript, to the server.  I perform calculations on the data and post the json results on the iis express server webpage.  How do I get that data using angular?

Here is my angular api service file that allow me to post to the server

```
export class ApiService {

private handleError: HandleError;

constructor(
 private http: HttpClient,
 httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
 this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('HeroesService');
}

stock: StockComponent ;

stockURL = 'https://localhost:44310/api/stock'

/** POST: */
postStock (stock) {
  console.log('stock is ', stock);
  this.http.post(this.stockURL, stock).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
})

}
 getBuySellData(){
   return this.http.get('https://localhost:44310/api/stock');
}

 }
```

Here is the component file:

```
  export class StockComponent {
stock = {}
constructor(private api: ApiService){

}

post(stock){
  console.log('this is the stock ', stock)
    this.api.postStock(stock)
}
```

Here is part of the controller in visual studio

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Models.Stock stock)
    {
        _context.Stocks.Add(stock);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(stock);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<DateCloseBuySell> GetQuote()
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;
```

Comment: First you should check if your response looks like expected using your browsers network monitor. Then it's the first param in your callback (your console.log(res) should already log the result from your server. What do you get / see on console and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Chris, I can post successfully, I wlll look at the log for get

"  getBuySellData(){
    this.http.get(this.stockURL).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble in Xamarin.Forms.

To solve it I did something like:

```
private const string Url = "https://localhost:44310/api/stock";

private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

protected async void OnGetList()
{
    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
        try 
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);

            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(content);
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand the starter uses angular as the client side while you posted C# client code.

Comment: Chris,  I think I get what you are saying, the answer is in C# and I need typscript/javascript code for the client to access the json data on the server

Answer (score 0):

I modified api.service.ts to

```
stock: StockComponent ;

stockURL = 'https://localhost:44310/api/stock'

/** POST: */
postStock (stock) {
  this.http.post(this.stockURL, stock).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
}

getBuySellData(){
  this.http.get(this.stockURL).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
```

and the component.ts to

```
    constructor(private api: ApiService){

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getBuySellData()
}

post(stock){

    this.api.postStock(stock)
}
```

I see the json data in my client console window.  Thanks Chris.